# Prefab null Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image: inspector view prefab]

The prefab is coming as null, even though I already assigned it in Unity. I already searched in many places I still haven't found out where the error is exactly.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ButtonManager : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameObject myPrefab;
    public Transform Panel;

    public void distribution(List<InventoryItem> list){
        for (int i=0; i<list.Count; i++){

            Instantiate(myPrefab, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
       }
    }
}
```

[image: editor interface]

Is it maybe the way I am assigning the `button_manager_script`?

[UPDATE] ButtonScriptOne

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ButtonScriptOne : MonoBehaviour {

    public ButtonManager button_manager_script;

    void Start () {
        button_manager_script = new ButtonManager();
    }

    public void test_function(){
        GlobalState.lazyLoad = true;
        var list_items = new List<InventoryItem>();
        list_items = DataStore.FindAllItems();

        Debug.Log("First: "+ list_items[0]);

        button_manager_script.distribution(list_items);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include the code where the assignment statement is occurring?

Comment: You most likely have attached the script on several objects and `distribution` is called on the component which is not set up. Run a simple `Debug.Log("Distribution called on component " + name, this );` and click on the message in the console to highlight the gameObject holding the called `ButtonManager`.

Comment: It's only assigned to one GameObject :/

Comment: Then can you please include a screenshot of the object's inspector window, and a full copy of the stack trace of the error from the console?

Comment: @LouisIngenthron done^

Comment: Hmmm... looks okay so far.  Can you please also add a screenshot of the prefab's inspector view?

Comment: @LouisIngenthron done^

Comment: I don't know... given what you've shown us, it should work.  The only thing I can see is that it says the error is on line 25, but it would be 15 in the example you've shown us.  Are we missing any code there?

Comment: The error is coming from `ButtonScriptOne` and you've shown us `ButtonManager`.

Comment: @Draco18s I've added the ButtonScriptOne

Comment: The "myPrefab" is returning Null. But I assigned it in Unity (as seen in the image) so it shouldn't be null, right? Or should I have to do something in the code to make the connection with Unity?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it maybe the way I am assigning the button_manager_script?

## Yes

1: `button_manager_script = new ButtonManager();` You can't do this. `ButtonManager` is a MonoBehaviour and Unity should have complained to you for calling `new` instead of `AddComponent` (or `GetComponent`). I don't know why it didn't, or if you ignored that error and cleared it out of the console.

2: Because you somehow managed to do that *anyway* your non-attached component has a null `myPrefab` field because you never set it to anything from within `ButtonScriptOne`.

Comment: so how should it be? im new in unity and I saw in many places people addressing it like that... The thing is that I print the button_manager_script and it's says it's not null in the ButtonScriptOne...

Comment: If it inherits from "Monobehaviour", you should create game objects in hierachy like ButtonManager gameObject, ButtonScriptOne gameObject, etc.. then assign them in inspector. You cant create objects virtually with "new" statements, if it is "Monobehaviour". This is how unity game engine functions..

Comment: @uint You have a ButtonManager attached to your object. Call `GetComponent<ButtonManager>` to get a reference to your button manager.